# insmod: ERROR: could not insert module dvb-usb-it913x.ko: Unknown symbol in module

Tags: c, linux, makefile, linux-device-driver, nanopi

I am trying the device driver for nanopi.
I can download the linux source code with
`git clone https://github.com/friendlyarm/linux.git -b sunxi-4.14.y --depth 1`

Also, the `make` command is work, and genereated the `dvb-usb-it913x.ko` file, but, I cannot install to my nano pi.  How I can fix this problem?

Below is module's information.

```
root@NanoPi-NEO-Core:/home/pi/it913x_driver# modinfo dvb-usb-it913x.ko
filename:       /home/pi/it913x_driver/dvb-usb-it913x.ko
license:        GPL
version:        v18.05.21.1
description:    Driver for devices based on ITEtech IT913x
author:         Figo Chang <Figo.Chang@ite.com.tw>
license:        GPL
description:    Driver for the IT913x demodulator
author:         Figo Chang <Figo.Chang@ite.com.tw>
srcversion:     741FE5FD33216AB55995F3F
alias:          usb:v048Dp9135d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v048Dp9006d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v048Dp9005d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
depends:
name:           dvb_usb_it913x
vermagic:       4.14.111 SMP mod_unload ARMv7 p2v8
parm:           debug:Set debugging level.(info = 1, deb_fw = 2, deb_fwdata = 4, deb_data = 8) (debugging is not enabled) (int)
parm:           remote:int
parm:           URB_BUFSIZE:URB_BUFSIZE = 188*xxx (int)
parm:           adapter_nr:DVB adapter numbers (array of short
```

```
root@/nano:/# uname -r
4.14.111
```

```
root@/nano:/# uname -a
Linux NanoPi-NEO-Core 4.14.111 #64 SMP Mon May 20 15:32:02 CST 2019 armv7l armvl armv7l GNU/Linux
```

```
root@/nano:/# dmsg
[ 2038.589152] dvb_usb_it913x: Unknown symbol dvb_usb_device_init (err 0)
[ 2038.589181] dvb_usb_it913x: Unknown symbol dvb_usb_device_exit (err 0)
```

Comment: `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");` is important?

Comment: How I can read https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ChangeLog-4.14.1 ?

Comment: Have you tried `modprobe whatever.ko` instead of `insmod /path/to/whatever.ko`?